# Scala, F-Bounded polymorphism not working as expected

Tags: scala, generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have the following classes related to IpAddresses.  I defined IpAddress this way because I wanted to enforce that each subtype of IpAddress can only be compared with itself.  Meaning, it would be senseless to compare an Ipv4 to an Ipv6

```
sealed trait IpAddress[T <: IpAddress[T]] extends Comparable[IpAddress[T]] {
  val address: Array[Byte]

  override def compareTo(that: IpAddress[T]): Int = ???
}

case class Ipv4Address(address: Array[Byte]) extends IpAddress[Ipv4Address]{
  assert(address.length == 4)
}

case class Ipv6Address(address: Array[Byte]) extends IpAddress[Ipv6Address]{
  assert(address.length == 16)
}
```

Now I'm trying to use an IpAddress in a different context like this:

```
def doSomethingWithComparables[K <: Comparable[K]](k: K): Int = k.compareTo(k)
```

but for some reason, I can't use an IpAddress here.

```
doSomethingWithComparables(Ipv4Address(Array(0,0,0,0)))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: inferred type arguments [main.Main.Ipv4Address] do not conform to method doSomethingWithComparables's type parameter bounds [K <: Comparable[K]]
```

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your F-bound class needs to extend `Comparable[T]` rather than `Comparable[IpAddress[T]]` so you are comparing the bound class not the base class:

```
sealed trait IpAddress[T <: IpAddress[T]] extends Comparable[T] {
  val address: Array[Byte]

  override def compareTo(that: T): Int = ???
}
```